# How to apply background image to body of the asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css

I want to apply background image to the body of asp.net page.
I have tried like this:

```
body
{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight:bold;
  background-image:url('C:\Users\ARCHANA\Downloads\Opera-Background-Blue-Swirls.jpg');
}
```

Its is getting applied in the design part, but when I run the application, the image is not applied. I cant figure out what is the problem. Can anyone kindly help me. Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't reference a local file like that on a web server.  Copy it somewhere in your application and reference it using a URI, ie,

```
background-image:url('/Images/Opera-Background-Blue-Swirls.jpg');
```

Comment: why forward slash is used, when I copy the link I get backward slash.

Comment: @ArchanaB.R it's just convention for URI paths, as opposed to local file system paths.

Comment: Forward slashes are used in URLs.  Backward slashes are used in Windows OS (DOS).

Answer (score 1):

You have to give `url` not the `directory path`.

```
body
{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight:bold;
  background-image:url('http://yourwebsite.com/Users/ARCHANA/Downloads/Opera-Background-Blue-Swirls.jpg');
}
```